# Saved cookies wont access old session in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, pickle

new to python programming here. I am trying to access chase without having to do email authentication. I have saved cookies using selenium and pickle after logging in and added them into a new session.

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(filepath)
driver.get("https://secure07a.chase.com/web/auth/dashboard#/dashboard")
```

After logging in manually I save the cookies into pickle:

```
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

Accessing cookies in another script:

```
import pickle
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(filepath)
driver.get("https://secure07a.chase.com/web/auth/dashboard#/dashboard")
for cookie in pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb")):
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    print(cookie)

driver.get("https://secure07a.chase.com/web/auth/dashboard#/dashboard")
driver.find_element_by_id('userId-input-field').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('password-input-field').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id('signin-button').click()
```

At which point the site asks me to authenticate with my email.

The cookies are added to the current domain. I have tried using the firefox default profile with firefox webdriver but I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. Some browser cookies change each time you log in so you must save the current session and load that session the next time you run.